# Manual breaks of facet_wrap() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Problem**

I am trying to understand how to provide y-axis breaks manually to facets, generated by the `facet_wrap()` function in `ggplot2` in `R`.

**Minimal reproducible example**

Disclaimer: I have borrowed the following example from the [R studio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/separate-axis-breaks-for-facets/10352/3)

With the following code, you can specify the y-axis breaks based on the y-axis values in de dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)
diamonds2 <- subset(diamonds, !(cut == "Fair" & price > 5000))

my_breaks <- function(x) { if (max(x) < 6000) seq(0, 5000, 1000) else seq(0, 15000, 5000) }

ggplot(data = diamonds2, aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  facet_wrap(~ cut, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = my_breaks)
```

[image]

**Question**

I would like to be able to specify the breaks manually, based on the `facet` (in this case: based on the 'cut' of the diamonds). For example, I would like to set the breaks for the 'Fair' cut to `seq(1000, 2500, 5000)`, the breaks for the 'Good' cut to `seq(1500, 3000, 4500, 6000, ..., 15000)` and the rest to `seq(0,15000, 5000)`.

**Attempt**

I thought that adapting the `my_breaks` function with an if-else-ladder, specifying the 'cut' would solve the problem, however, it doesn't:

```
my_breaks <- function(x) { 
  if (cut == "Fair") {seq(0, 5000, 1000) }
  else if (cut == "Good") {seq(1500,15000, 1500)}
  else { seq(0, 15000, 5000) }
}
```

It provides the error:

> Error in cut == "Fair" :    comparison (1) is possible only for atomic
>   and list types

Is there another approach to manually provide the breaks to different facets?

Comment: I assume, the error occurs, because in the function you've created ```cut``` refers to a function in base r (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut). Even, if you pass cut somehow as argument to the function, I'm not sure, whether it would work properly. Wouldn't ```facet_wrap(~ cut, scales = "free") +``` (i.e. also keeping x-axis free) work for you?

Comment: I don't think `my_breaks` function has any idea of which `cut` it is in. That information is not passed to it.

Comment: @WolfgangArnold No, I would like to be able to specify the breaks of the y-axis manually.

Comment: @RonakShah Ah, that is a problem, yes! Do you have an idea, how to solve that problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try defining each facet manually by filtering the data and then "patch" the plot up using [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) package

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

my_plot <- function(df, var, sc) {
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  facet_grid(~ {{var}}) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = {{sc}})
}

diamonds2 <- subset(diamonds, !(cut == "Fair" & price > 5000))

p1 <- diamonds2 %>% filter(cut == "Fair") %>% my_plot(var = "Fair",  sc = c(0, 5000))
p2 <- diamonds2 %>% filter(cut == "Good") %>% my_plot(var = "Good",  sc = c(0, 15000))
p3 <- diamonds2 %>% filter(cut == "Very Good") %>% my_plot(var = "Very Good",  sc = c(0, 1000))
p4 <- diamonds2 %>% filter(cut == "Premium") %>% my_plot(var = "Premium",  sc = c(0, 500))
p5 <- diamonds2 %>% filter(cut == "Ideal") %>% my_plot(var = "Ideal",  sc = c(0, 20000))

p1+p2+p3+p3+p4+plot_layout(ncol = 3)
```

[image]

edit: I realized it was the y-axis breaks to be set pr. facet. In that case

```
my_plot <- function(df, var, my_breaks) {
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  facet_grid(~ {{var}}) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = {{my_breaks}})
}

library(ggplot2)
diamonds2 <- subset(diamonds, !(cut == "Fair" & price > 5000))

p1 <- diamonds2 %>% filter(cut == "Fair") %>% my_plot(var = "Fair",  my_breaks = seq(0, 5000, 1000))
p2 <- diamonds2 %>% filter(cut == "Good") %>% my_plot(var = "Good",  my_breaks = seq(1500,15000, 1500))
p3 <- diamonds2 %>% filter(cut == "Very Good") %>% my_plot(var = "Very Good",  my_breaks =seq(1500,15000, 5000))
p4 <- diamonds2 %>% filter(cut == "Premium") %>% my_plot(var = "Premium",  my_breaks = seq(1500,15000, 5000))
p5 <- diamonds2 %>% filter(cut == "Ideal") %>% my_plot(var = "Ideal",  my_breaks = seq(1500,15000, 5000))

p1+p2+p3+p3+p4+plot_layout(ncol = 3)
```

[image]

Edit2:
A leaner way to do this using purrr

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(purrr)
facets = diamonds2 %>% distinct(cut) %>% pull()
my_breaks = list(seq(0, 5000, 1000), seq(1500,15000, 1500), seq(1500,15000, 5000),
                 seq(1500,15000, 5000), seq(1500,15000, 5000))

plt_list <- purrr::map2(facets, my_breaks, ~my_plot(diamonds2, .x, .y))

Reduce('+', plt_list) + plot_layout(ncol = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is a nice workaround! I have one concern, though: by filtering all the datasets separately (in this case based on the 'cut'), we nullify the advantages of the use of facets. If we use the `filter` option first than facetting will not have a purpose anymore. With 5 plots, the option is manageable; however, with 15 plots we encounter scalability issues. Any ideas if this can be circumvented? But again, thanks for the workaround!

Comment: Using `purrr::` and `patchwork` we can create our own custom faceting function. I have updated the answer to show how.

Comment: The reason the `my_plot` is using `facet_grid` on filtered data is simply to nicely add the facet label on top of each panel.